# String is nil when converting back from NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bitarray

I'm attempting to encrypt a hexadecimal string with a C library, a heroic feat that bridges Swift, Objective-C and C.

However the end result when I convert my `NSData` to a `String` is `nil`.

I start with this:

```
let fakeHex = "9F1D53E732E48F25F94711D5B22086778278624F715D9B2BEC8FB81134E7C904".toData()
let data = Data(repeating: 1, count: 32)
```

`data` is a set of 32 `true` values

`fakeHex` is a hard-coded hexadecimal that I run through the following extension to UTF8 encode it:

```
extension String {

    func toData() -> Data {
        let data = NSMutableData()
        let terminator = [0]
        for char in self {
            let encodedString = String(char).data(using: .utf8)!
            data.append(encodedString)
            data.append(terminator, length: 1)
        }

        return Data(referencing: data)
    }

}
```

Next, I have an Objective-C class called `Blakey` that takes the hex `NSData` and the `true`s `NSData` and hashes them via the [Blake2](http://blake2.net) hashing algorithm:

```
let x = Blakey().createKeyPair(withHexData: fakeHex, andIndexData: data)
```

^ this returns some NSData as well

```
- (NSData *)createKeyPairWithHexData:(NSData *)data andIndexData:(NSData *)indexData;
{
    struct blake2b_state__ state;
    blake2b_init(&state, 32);

    blake2b_update(&state, data.bytes, data.length); // data.length is 128
    blake2b_update(&state, indexData.bytes, indexData.length); // indexData.length is 32

    void *foo = malloc(32);
    blake2b_final(&state, foo, 32);

    NSData *accountKey = [NSData dataWithBytes:foo length:32];

    free(foo);

    return accountKey;
}
```

This code is modeled off of what's going on in a companion implementation in Python:

```
def seed_account(seed, index):
    # (seed here is our hex string, index is 1)
    # Given an account seed and index #, provide the account private and public keys
    h = blake2b(digest_size=32)

    seed_data = BitArray(hex=seed)
    seed_index = BitArray(int=index,length=32)

    h.update(seed_data.bytes)
    h.update(seed_index.bytes)

    return account_key = BitArray(h.digest())
```

Finally, I take the `NSData` from the `Blakey` function and try to turn it into a string:

```
NSString(data: x!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
String(data: x!, encoding: .utf8)
```

Both print `nil`.

I'm doing something wrong in the process, not sure what. Would love some help if anything stands out.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually the extension encodes the string `utf16`. You can do the same with `"9F1D5...C904".data(using: .utf16)!`. However the built-in solutions adds the BOM `FFFE`

Comment: I realize I can do that but where are you getting the `utf16` from? My code is `let encodedString = String(char).data(using: .utf8)!`

Comment: Changing to `utf16` interestingly makes it return Chinese and Japanese, rather than nil `Optional("냨ひ箹刚頶苩Ǜ䭋止ᒊ䙩꾩㓋龘")`

Comment: Simple question: Is `x` supposed to even represent a String?

Comment: Your `toData()` extension converts each character to `utf8` and adds a zero byte which is practically the same as converting to `utf16` for the given string.

Comment: @vadian Thanks. I imagine I want to encode in utf8, although that returns me nil

Comment: @Larme I figured that taking a string, breaking it down to data, encrypting it and returning its data, then converting to a string _would_ represent a string, but maybe I'm wrong. I guessed the hashing algorithm would take a B, do its magic, return a 9 or 5 as bytes, then I could transform its data back to a string

Comment: @Larme now that I look at the other code, most of it is dealing with bytes until much later when it encodes and spits it back out after some more transformation, but still, at this point shouldn't I be able to convert some data that was previously a string and was encrypted back to a string that looks different since it's been encrypted?

Comment: Not necessarly. The point is to encrypt a String (which make a "sense" as a String). It convert it to a Data with some algorithm. The encrypteddata doesn't need to make sense by itself, it needs to be decrypted back to make sense. You may use `base64EncodedStringWithOptions:` when it's a "data" mode to get a "string", or in other words, make it "human readable", but that's just a guess.

Comment: Got it Thanks. Got some more steps to go I guess

Answer (score 0):

You append terminator after each character, but you probably want to append it in the end of the string (this one `data.append(terminator, length: 1)`)